# duplicating a block on a diff page - magento

Tags: magento, static, e-commerce, block

I want to duplicate the view.phtml block that consists of the advanced search filters on the left side of this page:
http://47stphoto.simple-helix.net/brands/view/?brand=3

to be above the learning center block on this page:
http://47stphoto.simple-helix.net/catalogsearch/result/?q=Search+everyday+deals

Ive tried copying the view.phtml code in the catalog.xml file and putting it above the learning center .phtml and got php errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show in `catalogsearch_result_index` page go to catalogue.xml in this tag and create this lines:

```
<reference name="search.layer.view">
      <block type="catalogsearch/layer" name="catalogsearch.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

And then create new reference within default tag in page.xml:

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="search.layer.view" as="search.layer.view" translate="label">
        </block>
```

Then call it in your learning center phtml as follows:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('search.layer.view') ?>
```

I think this will help you :-]